# SplitView within TabBarContoller on iPad

Tags: ipad

Could anybody please suggest the route to create splitview on top of TabBarViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I just read this :

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from
>   aUISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split-view interface may then contain
>   navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view
>   controller you need to implement your interface.

on this [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW1) at Apple's developer webpage. I imagine that in the mainwindow.xib you have to add a tabbbarcontroller alongside the splitviewcontroller and then add it to the detail view in the corresponding view you want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

> The split view controller’s view
>   should always be installed as the root
>   view of your application window. You
>   should never present a split view
>   inside of a navigation or tab bar
>   interface.

[iPad Programming Guide...](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html)

You need to rethink the design, or roll your own tabs (but apple would quite possibly reject anything like that).

Comment: where did you read about it? Is impossible to use a split view inside a navigation-based app?